# how to get sum of any column group by with like statement in sql

Tags: sql

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rB9v.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5UFI.png)

In above image we 3 user along with -1, -2 , -3 like, ihusain, ihusain-1, how to get group by sum on userid, result required combine like for ihusain, ihusain-1, ihusain-2 for these userid result should be single ihusain and same for other,

Need all user together same like we get some with group by from any table

Need all user together same like we get some with group by from any table

Comment: Please tag your question with the dbms you are using.  It's useless if someone provide a solution, but it's for the wrong dbms like below.  It's a waste of everybody's time!!!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify database you use; solution depends on that.

---

Anyway, whichever database it is, you'll have to get rid of the suffix, somehow. The following example is **Oracle**; I used regular expression for that purpose.

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from test;

USERID        AMOUNT
--------- ----------
ihusain           10
ihusain-1         50
ihusain-2         50
rdesoza           84
rdesoza-3        574
rdesoza-5         56

6 rows selected.
```

Query:

```
SQL> select regexp_substr(userid, '\w+'), sum(amount) total
  2  from test
  3  group by regexp_substr(userid, '\w+');

REGEXP_SUBSTR(USERID,'\W+')               TOTAL
------------------------------------ ----------
ihusain                                     110
rdesoza                                     714

SQL>
```

---

According to error message you reported in a comment, it looks like you use **MS SQL Server**. In that case, here's one option for that database:

```
select case when charindex('-', userid) = 0 then userid
            else substring(userid, 1, charindex('-', userid) - 1)
       end as user_name,
       sum(amount) total
from test
group by case when charindex('-', userid) = 0 then userid
              else substring(userid, 1, charindex('-', userid) - 1)
         end;
```

Its fiddle is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/LXbiVjQ9).

Comment: Still having issue with this query.  -------- Error: 

Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 3
'regexp_substr' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: As I said: this is example that works in Oracle. Which database do you use? SQL tag is for a **language** (Structured Query Language), but every database vendor has its own *flavor* and they *differ*. Not everything works everywhere.

Comment: Apparently, you use MS SQL Server. Have a look at edited answer, please.